# Codenvy angular setup not showing page

Tags: angularjs, codenvy

I have setup an angular project at codenvy.io. I have configured a runserver command as stated in this article:
https://eclipse.org/che/docs/tutorials/angular2/index.html

I was able to to compile the project successfully and, generate a preview url (check the image below). However, when I navigate to the url, I only see an empty page instead of "app works" (the default angular page).

What configuration have I missed?

Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --public-host ${server.4200} --live-reload=false

It works for me with angular-cli 6.0.7